# Diagonalisation of high dimensional matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have to find the matrix $P$ such that $A=PDP^{-1}$. I thus proceeded to compute

```
Transpose[Normalize /@ Eigenvectors[A]]
```

and everything worked perfectly for 4×4 or 6×6 matrices. For a 16×16 matrix it takes 4-5 minutes. In the future I may be asked to find $P$ for a matrix of dimension $n>16$.

Is there a way to diagonalize a matrix in such a manner to avoid this awfully long computational time?

Comment: Have you read about `JordanDecomposition` in the documentation? It is almost instantaneous for n=16 (working with real numbers)

Comment: I note that you have neglected to say anything about your matrix's special properties, e.g. symmetry or sparsity...

Comment: If the input matrix is numerical and a numeric approximation is acceptable, use `N[A]` to avoid the (huge) speed hit of working with exact eigenvalues/vectors.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I figured it out later shortly after posting the question. For everyone else trying this: ALWAYS use $N[A]$, as Daniel said, when you compute high dimensional matrices, if it's for data analysis purposes (so you work with numbers and you don't need an analytical solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `JordanDecomposition` :

```
m = RandomReal[10, {16, 16}];
First@RepeatedTiming[JordanDecomposition[m]]

(* 0.00016 sec *)
```

In the case that $n=32$, then it takes `0.00056 sec`, for $n=320$ then `0.13`, all in a 6 years-old Intel i7.

However, take care when your matrices have only integer numbers, be advised that the calculation will be slow.

Comment: What are you doing there? For $n = 32$, I get 0.000762 seconds. 0.0655435 looks more like $n = 320$... ;)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, it seems that I have a Ford T computer, and you a La Ferrari one ;))...This also has to do with other computer simultaneous tasks anyway...

Comment: Nah, what I meant was that the timing for $n = 32$ should be much closer to your timing for $n = 16$...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher thanks for paying this to my attention. Cheched by using `RepeatedTimig` and corrected...

Comment: Look, now yours is even faster than mine... :)